# How to hide static method

Tags: c#, polymorphism, static-methods

Let's say I have a classes, like that:

```
class A
{
   public static int Count()
}
class B : A
{
}
class C : A
{
}
```

How can I hide this static method for class B but not for C?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't, basically. Heck, if it's public then *anyone* can call it.

You could make it protected which would allow it to be called from within B or C but not elsewhere... but you still couldn't differentiate between B and C.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by creating another class, let's call it Special, that inherits A. Then you would make C inherit from Special and B inherit from A. Also, you would have the static method protected, that means only classes that inherited Special will have access to it.

```
class A
{
}
class Special : A
{
    protected static int Count()
}
class B : A
{
}
class C : Special
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution would be to change your class hierarchy. *It's not worth the hassle and WTF moments you will get in code reviews it if you ask me.*

```
class ABase
{
}
class A
{
   public static int Count()
}
class B : ABase
{
}
class C : ABase
{
}
```